# Cannot create Android AVD

Tags: android, emulation, android-sdcard, android-virtual-device

I am unable to create the android avd. whenever i try to create one through eclipse, i get the following error. I tried everything but went in vain. I am attaching a snap shot, please have a look at it.

[image: Error Log]

Comment: I had a similar experience once. i was running from windows and it helped me open Eclipse as administrator, however, if you are not running in windows or allready running as administrator i do not know what is wrong

Comment: im on windows and have administrator privileges

Answer (score 0):

First try it in command line as follows: "android create avd-n-c 64M-myAvd tx" (x for target, you can get  list of targets with "android list targets").If the problem persists, be sure you have  write permission in the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mksdcard in tools directory was corrupted. So, i downloaded another mksdcard file from the below site:

http://www.wuala.com/cerealkiller37/HTC/Sdk%20Android/android/tools/mksdcard.exe/

It worked!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the sdCard size to 64M